# Need to unstick stuck shower divider valve

Tags: plumbing, repair, bathroom, shower

The shower divider value (which chooses between letting water flow into the tub or up into the shower) is stuck. I can't spin it with the installed plastic handle. Here's some pictures:

With the handle
[image: with handle]

No handle
[image: no handle]

From the side
[image: from the side]

How much force can I apply when trying to spin it?

What can I do to get it loose?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture, but it looks like the value is designed to be removed with a hex key (aka Allen wrench). You could try soaking it in vinegar or CLR and see if you can free it with a hex key socket to remove/clean it.  Brass is a fairly soft metal, so if you go this route be careful not to strip it out.

Comment: Thanks @Comintern! I have a screwdriver that fits it almost perfectly. I'll try the vinegar soak!